# Can any one explain the usage of Shell::Source perl module or Shell::GetEnv module

Tags: linux, perl, perl-module, perltk

I m a beginner in `perl`. I want to know how to use this module. I read somewhere about this module but not getting its usage.

Actually I've a file which contains some environment paths which needs to be set while running some test(say file name is `SET_ENV_TOOL1.csh` or `SET_ENV_TOOL1.sh`) with particular tools.(say `TOOL1`, `TOOL2` etc)

```
SET_ENV_TOOL1.sh file conatins:
setenv UVM_HOME /u/tools/digital/uvm/uvm-1.1a
setenv VIPP_HOME /u/tools/digital/vipcat_11.30-s012-22-05-2012
setenv VIP_AXI_PATH ${VIPP_HOME}/vips/amba_axi/vr_axi/sv/ #etc.(almost 10-15 paths are need to be set like this)
```

Everytime while running test, tool might get changed and so environment paths also needs to set to run that tool.

I have to make a perl script which sets these paths before running test. That test will run a command and that command will use these environment paths.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

[Reading and changing environment variables is built-in to Perl](http://p3rl.org/var#%25ENV), you do not need the modules you mentioned.

```
$ENV{UVM_HOME} = '/u/tools/digital/uvm/uvm-1.1a';
$ENV{VIPP_HOME} = '/u/tools/digital/vipcat_11.30-s012-22-05-2012';
$ENV{VIP_AXI_PATH} = "$ENV{VIPP_HOME}/vips/amba_axi/vr_axi/sv/";
```